# porque mi codigo javascript no me deja cambiar de imagen mas de una vez?

Tags: javascript

estoy usando el siguiente codigo ,, solo me deja cambiar de imagen una vez  y despues ya no hace mas cambios se supone deveria cambiar cada vez que hago click

```
     <script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var opn = 0;

        $('#este').click(function () {
            if (opn == 0) {
                document.getElementById('change').src = "css/galeria/flechita_blanca.png"
                opn = 1;
            }
        });



        $('#este').click(function () {
            if (opn == 1) {
                document.getElementById('change').src = "css/galeria/down.png"
            }
            opn = 0;

        });
    });


</script>
```

Comment: estas reescribiendo el evento click siempre te tomara el segundo siempre , y de hecho todo cabe en una funcion `var opn = 0;
$('#este').click(function () {
  if (opn == 1) {
    document.getElementById('change').src = "css/galeria/flechita_blanca.png"
    opn = 1;
  }else{
    document.getElementById('change').src = "css/galeria/flechita_blanca.png"
    opn = 0;
  }

});` tambien hay una opcion para eso que se llama [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

Answer (score 0):

intenta esto

```
  var opn = 0;
  $('#este').click(function () {
    if (opn == 0) {
        document.getElementById('change').src = "css/galeria/flechita_blanca.png"
        opn = 1;
    }else{
        document.getElementById('change').src = "css/galeria/down.png"
        opn = 0;
    }
    });
```

estas estas cruzando las funciones...

Comment: funciono gracias!